# How can I trigger a function in jQuery after an AJAX request alters a table?

Tags: jquery

I have my initTableStripes function that I call as soon as the document is ready.

The problem is that after an AJAX request that either alters a table or loads a new table I need to call the function again. There are quite a few plugins and other functions can alter or load a new table, so I'd prefer to not have to remember to call the initTableStripes function in each of these other functions.

Is there any way that I can tell jQuery to fire the function when a `<tbody>` is altered or when a table's wrapper `<div>`'s inner html is altered when a new table is loaded into it?

The following is what I had in mind:

```
$("tbody").live("change", function (e) {
    initTableStripes();
});
```

Of course the "change" event is limited to `<input>`, `<textarea>` and `<select>` elements. Is there a simple way to accomplish this or is it best to just keep manually calling the function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register a function to run when an AJAX request completes. You could perform your re-striping logic in there.

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Comment: +1. Definitely seems like a nicer way of handling this than my answer.

Comment: +1 good stuff! I advise to copy those 3 lines of code from the link and paste it into your answer, just in case the page won't be available in the future.